# Monitor applications

Tags: java

how to monitor external applications(like notepad/word/exce/media players..) from java

Comment: What about the external applications do you want to monitor?

Comment: what i meant was when notepad/excel is running if a fault occurs how do i capture it

Answer (score 2):

If you start them yourself with the [`Runtime`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class, you can probably monitor them that way.

But, if they're started outside of your control, WMI is the way I'd go.

The [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx) class is the one you're looking for, and [this page](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3297.htm) details how to do it in Java/JACOB (Java COM Bridge).

Comment: thanks
what exactly i want is whenever a fault occurs while running notepad/word/... , how to detect it

Comment: As the answer said, it depends on whether your Java process is starting the app. If it was, you'd be notified of a return value but it doesn't sound like that's what you want. It's going to be difficult, if not impossible, for an external program to tell whether an application crashed or exited cleanly.

Comment: yeah you are getting it right i am not starting the application from my program but still i want the exit status of that application. Is there any way to do it even i m trying it from past one week and i m in no mans land.Please help me to sort it out

Comment: Not through WMI, I don't believe it holds information once the processes have exited so, while you can tell they've disappeared, you can't tell why. I can think of a kludge that involves replacing notepad.exe with some of your own code which would call the real one and wait but, before we go down that path to insanity, can you tell us why you need this? There may be a better way.

Comment: the objective is to capture the fault if it has occured and store it in DB.
If any other go is also acceptable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you mean by monitoring and I am guessing that you are referring to a Windows platform. The only way to do something like this is to use a COM interface. Have a look at the [JACOB project](http://danadler.com/jacob/).

Comment: thanks
what exactly i want is whenever a fault occurs while running notepad/word/... , how to detect it